# openssl connect in a script

Tags: shell-script, scripting, openssl

I'm using `openssl s_client -connect` to extract the dates from a cert.

I want to integrate it into a bash script, the problem is that the command opens the connection to the server and waits for the input, making it not suitable for a noninteractive approach.

Any suggestions or alternatives? Thx

Comment: `openssl ... < /dev/null`?

Comment: Or `echo|openssl.....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like [Romeo Ninov mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/769268/openssl-connect-in-a-script#comment1468668_769268) in the comments, just pass `echo` to your `openssl` command:

```bash
echo | openssl s_client -connect ...
```

It will immediately close the connection.